# Как сравнить два DataFrame разного размера по одному столбцу?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два DataFrame - `df1` и `df2`. Оба DataFrame имеют разные размеры.
Нужно найти и удалить все строки в `df1`, которые есть в `df2`. Сравнение необходимо делать по одному столбцу.

```
df1

1                 2               3              4
text          111111111        text            text
text          222222222        text            text
text          333333333        text            text


df2

1                 2               3              4            5
text          2222222222        text           text         text
text          3333333333        text           text         text


Out df

  1                 2               3              4
  text          111111111        text            text
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: у вас во втором фрейме в столбце `2` значения не совпадают со значениями из фрейма `df1`: `222222222 != 2222222222`. Исправьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [165]: res = df1.append(df2[df1.columns]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

In [166]: res
Out[166]:
      1          2     3     4
0  text  111111111  text  text
```

Comment: Исходя из вопроса, я так понял, что требуется разность двух множеств `df_1[col] / df_2[col] ` . Ваш вариант возвращает _симмитрическую_ разность двух множеств `df_1[col] / df_2[col] `

Answer (score 0):

```
    Вот такая ошибка вылезла:

res = df_newb.append(df_ourb[df_newb.columns]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-d1429ec1d644> in <module>
----> 1 res = df_newb.append(df_ourb[df_newb.columns]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2804             if is_iterator(key):
   2805                 key = list(key)
-> 2806             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
   2807 
   2808         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1551 
   1552         self._validate_read_indexer(
-> 1553             keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
   1554         )
   1555         return keyarr, indexer

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1638             if missing == len(indexer):
   1639                 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1640                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1641 
   1642             # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in

KeyError: "None of [Index(['Название', 'ИНН','Адрес', 'Телефоны'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2586 entries, 0 to 2585
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                 --------------  ----- 
 0   Название               2586 non-null   object
 1   ИНН                    2586 non-null   int64 
 2   Адрес                  2586 non-null   object
 3   Телефоны               1042 non-null   object

dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 384.0+ KB
```

Answer (score 0):

Если сравнение делать по одному столбцу, то можно так (сравниваем по столбцу 2):

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({1: ['text', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text'], 
                     2: [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({1: ['text', 'text', 'text', 'text'], 
                     2: [22, 33, 66, 77]})

value_to_drop = df_2[2].values # значения, которые хотим исключить из df_1
flt = ~df_1[2].isin(value_to_drop) # оставляем только те значения, которые уникальны для df_1
df_1.loc[flt, :] # результат


      1     2
0   text    11
3   text    44
4   text    55
```

**UPD**
Сравнение по скорости с принятым ответом,

```
def test_one(df_1, df_2):
    value_to_drop = df_2[2].values 
    flt = ~df_1[2].isin(value_to_drop)
    return df_1.loc[flt, :] 

def test_two(df_1, df_2): #вариант MaxU
    return df_1.append(df_2[df_1.columns]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

%%timeit
test_one(df_1, df_2)
476 µs ± 5.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
test_two(df_1, df_2)
1.55 ms ± 12.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Хочу также отметить, что вариант ответа от MaxU так же возвращает значения, которые уникальны для df_2. В первом случае возвращается разность двух множеств, во втором - симмитрическая разность двух множеств

```
test_one(df_1, df_2)

      1     2
0   text    11
3   text    44
4   text    55

test_two(df_1, df_2)

      1     2
0   text    11
3   text    44
4   text    55
2   text    66
3   text    77
```

Comment: Круто! По крайней мере без ошибок отработало) Но в df_1 ничего не поменялось. Возможно это потому что в моем случае поле 2 в df_1 - int64, а поле 2 в df_2 - object . Может ли не работать из-за этого?

Comment: Чтобы изменить df_1 вам нужно прописать `df_1 = df_1.loc[flt, :]` , вместо `df_1.loc[flt, :]`

Comment: кстати, а это важно, если один df_1 размером : df_1.shape = (2586, 4), df_2.shape = (4444, 6) ?

Comment: вообщем сработало только когда во втором датафрейме перевел столбец в тип float64 .

Comment: Если у вас есть какие-то дополнительные условия, их необходимо определить в описании к задаче, тогда вы получите корректный ответ. Исходя из вашего примера, вы сравниваете по столбцу 2, где все значения `int` как в df_1, так и в df_2. Если поле object, скорее всего у вас значения в столбце - строка.

Comment: Да, не точно задачу описал. Вы все правильно говорите, действительно значения в столбце строка)

Comment: На вашем месте я бы проверил, почему столбец в df_2 является строкой: может вы так подгружаете dataframe. В том подходе, который я предложил, совершенно неважно, сколько столбцов в каждом из df. Главное, чтобы они были одного типа, то есть названия столбцов могут быть разные. Присмотритесь к методам `isin` и `loc` и как они работают.